# New folder is not shown in the JetBrains Rider hierarchy when created from external source

Tags: jetbrains-ide, rider, jetbrains-rider

Whenever I create a folder from Windows Explorer or Unity Project tab is it not visible in the Rider Explorer hierarchy. Here is an example:

[image]

**What happened before?**

I created a parent folder named `Interaction` with 4 subfolders called `Models`, `Controllers`, `Views` and `Installers`. Then I miss-clicked something like `Extract` button or whatever, and the subfolders gone.
But I undid that with <kbd>Ctrl + Z</kbd>, they returned.

But now new folders are not visible when created from external source.

Opening/closing Unity/Rider is not helping.

Comment: I you are using a project solution, you may need to to explicitly add existing folders and files to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you're mixing different things here: first of all, Rider has two different modes for the *Solution Explorer*:

- *Solution* → this is the mode you're currently using and it shows you all the added projects of your `*.sln` file.
- *File System* → this mode gives you a look into the file system.

When using the *File System* mode, you should see your newly created folders.

But when using the *Solution* mode, it's a bit trickier: only folders that contain C# files and are underneath an existing C# project folder are automatically added/displayed.
So if you've created empty folders without any `*.cs` files, Rider will show nothing as there is no code to display.

If you want to see the empty folders as well, you could click on *Show All Files* and add the folders manually - just keep in mind that this will update your `*.csproj` file.